# Firebase Cloud Firestore follow reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've  gotten a `queryDocumentSnapshot` with the following code:

```
mFireStore = FirbaseFirestore.getInstance();
mFireStore.collection("myCollection").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        // Set some data from the doc.getDocument here

mFireStore.collection("myCollection").document(doc.getDocument().getId()).collection("subCollection").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                                            // not found
                                        } else{

                                            List<DocumentSnapshot> hosts = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                                            for (int i = 0; i < hosts.size(); i++){
                                                // Each hosts DocumentSnapshot has a "host" field which contains a reference to a document
                                                // I'd like to follow this reference and get that document
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

My issue is that once I've gotten the list of host `DocumentSnapshots`, I'd like to follow their "host" field which contains a reference to a document.  I would like to follow this reference and get the document at the other end but do not know how. If you notice any other problems with my logic, feel free to point it out as I am very new to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: store these host ids in an array and then start listening to each ids

Comment: If you wanna achieve this you will need to do `NestedQueries` because you should do a single query for every document inside your "followed" user. Other way is do a cloud function that copies post from this user to a "feed" of the user who followed it, in that way you will be able to query always the feed, and avoid nested queries

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can simply iterate over the `hosts` list. If your `host` field holds the reference as a `String`, then please use the following lines of code:

```
for (DocumentSnapshot ds : hosts) {
    String host = ds.getString("host");
    Log.d("TAG", host);
}
```

If your `host` field holds the reference as a `DocumentReference`, then please use the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference host = ds.getDocumentReference("host");
```

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you tried my solution above?